# MAMP PRo Expired now I can run my wordpress app

Tags: wordpress, mamp

(macbook, yosemite, mamp pro 3.5)

I'm really disappointed with MAMP Pro.

I just spent a week making a wordpress site.

Now MAMP Pro has expired.
I expected a graceful downgrade to plain MAMP.

But no. Now my wordpress site can't find the database.

I never got a chance to export the database.. now I appear to be screwed.

Can anyone help me get back to where I was yesterday?

I started MAMP and in phpmyadmin there is no sign of the wordpress database.. just a 'mysql' database...

Does MAMP Pro delete the database when it expires ?
Are the files around somewhere so I could copy them over onto the db folder under mamp in the applications folder?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general MAMP Pro MySQL dbs are here : `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/`

If not, search for your database name (or for the name of a wordpress table like "`wp_posts`"), it will give you the db files location.

When you find the folder, copy it to MAMP db folder (shoud be something like `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP/db/mysql/`).

If not, creates a db with a particular name in MAMP and then search for that name to find MAMP dbs location.

Comment: Thank you vey much RafH.
The folder for my db was indeed under 
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql

Comment: BUT - I had to copy the folder into a different place, probably cos version of MAMP:
/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql

And the db shows up in phpMyAdmin... but I cannot browse any table data.
When I look at, say, the wp_users table and try to Browse the data I get an error "1146 - Table 'westsurv.wp_users' doesn't exist."

Comment: And when I point my browser at the wordpress site it goes into Install mode by going to install.php...
So I think that means the db is empty somehow...

Comment: Try to move all the mamp pro mysql directory, not only the db one. Then copy your old WP directory to MAMP www folder. You may need to edit wp-config.php to update db settings if they changed.

Comment: Oh you little Beauty!!
Thanks very much RafH.